# Input text in form-field, generate multiple URLs on submit and open the links in new tabs

Tags: javascript, forms, url

I'm looking to input text that is then used to generate multiple URLs and open each of them in a different tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gv5bq/1/

```
    <input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/print/' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://www.anywebsite.com/print/' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />
```

basically does what I need but just for one instead of multiple URLs.

For example:
Input: **hello123**
On submit open a tab for each of the following URLs
For example www.mywebsite.com/print/**hello123**/ and www.anywebsite.net/q=**hello123**&sort

Answer (score 0):

You find a code example below

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="openURLs(document.getElementById('text').value)"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function openURLs(url){
  var baseURLs = [`www.mywebsite.com/print/${url}/`, `www.anywebsite.net/q=${url}&sort`]

  baseURLs.forEach(function(u) {
    window.open(u);
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it's not working. Nothing happens when I click 'Submit'.

Comment: Hi @Chris ,the script is correct, but the target domains must allow a window of a different domain to open. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337916/why-is-window-open-blocked/337917#337917

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openURL(){
     var txt = document.getElementById('text').value;
     var link1 = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/print/'+ txt;
     var link2 = 'http://www.anywebsite.com/q='+ txt + '&sort';
     var i;
    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++){
      if(i == 1)
      {
        window.open(link1, '_blank');  
      }
      else if (i==2)
      {
      //it will be execute after 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
         window.open(link2, '_blank');  
         }, 5000);
       }
    }
     
      
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="openURL()">
```

I updated the fiddle [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/egyqd5cn/4/). It will give you result as you want. For Eg: If you enter `hello123` below respected url's will be open

1. http://www.mywebsite.com/print/hello123
2. http://www.anywebsite.com/q=hello123&sort

Comment: Thanks for sharing that but when I hit 'Submit' then nothing happens.

Comment: @Chris I updated the answer check it now it will works or check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/egyqd5cn/

Comment: thanks for that. Unfortunately only one of the 1st of the 2 URLs opens.

Comment: check the above jsfiddle both url's are working fine, but you should allow popup for the website.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks! How would the code look like if there is some more fixed values after the variable text input, see example from my original question.

Comment: @Chris I updated the answer check here https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/egyqd5cn/4/

Comment: Thanks @Udhay Titus That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Is there any way of setting a delay time? E.g. I want URL 1 to load right away and URL 2 will load 5 secs later etc.

Comment: @Chris Yes you can do by using `setTimeOut(function(){},5000);` or check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check Always Allow Pop-ups then use this code

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascriptFun()" />
<script>
function javascriptFun(){
window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/print/' + document.getElementById('text').value,'_blank');
window.open('http://www.mywebsite1.com/print/' + document.getElementById('text').value,'_blank');
window.open('http://www.mywebsite2.com/print/' + document.getElementById('text').value,'_blank');

}

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for that. How would the code look like if there is some more fixed values after the variable text input, see example from my original question: www.anywebsite.net/q=hello123&sort