# How can I target multiple URLs, using a single form and keyword?

Tags: html, database, tabs, search-engine, urlencode

I am trying to create something (basically a search engine, more or less), where I can enter a keyword into the search box, and that keyword will be implemented into several predefined URLs, and open multiple tabs with the search term for the respective pages. I know this is somewhat basic, but for the life of me, I can't pull my thoughts together to make it happen.

Example:

```
Search for: PHUN
```

The following links would be modified and open new tabs/pages with the search term.

```
https://dilutiontracker.com/app/search/PHUN
https://flash-sec.com/companysearch/?ticker=PHUN
https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/entityName=PHUN
```

Ideally, I would like to build a custom search engine where I could just add it to my browser and execute this straight from the search bar. Alternatively, I could use a simple HTML (or similar) page.

=========================================================

This is ultimately what I ended up using, the only downside is that the pop-up blocker prevents the tabs opening after the first link on the first attempt, but they open as soon as you allow them (at least in Firefox).

```
<input type="text" id="text" /> 
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" onclick="javascriptFun()" />

<script>
function javascriptFun(){
window.open('https://dilutiontracker.com/app/search/' + document.getElementById('text').value,'_blank');
window.open('https://flash-sec.com/companysearch/?ticker=' + document.getElementById('text').value,'_blank');
window.open('https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/entityName=' + document.getElementById('text').value,'_blank');

}

// (Could not press enter to submit) Listen for Enter key press on the input field
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action to stop submitting the form
        javascriptFun(); // Call the function to open the websites
    }
});

</script>
```

=========================================================

I found this post describing how to accomplish this using a web page/form:

[Input text in form-field, generate multiple URLs on submit and open the links in new tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882848/input-text-in-form-field-generate-multiple-urls-on-submit-and-open-the-links-in)

This will work for now. My goal is to create a search engine shortcut for web browsers that will execute this automatically from the address bar, but if anyone has a link or some code to get there quicker, let me know.

Comment: Have you thought about a `Form` element, with `action="GET"`? 

Comment: Why separate tabs?  Why wouldn't your (meta) search engine collect the results from several other search engines and show them on a single page?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The idea is to cause each of these URL's return the search term within their respective sites. These sites each have a different set of data related to the search term. They also require the user to be logged in to view some of the data, which would complicate things further trying to pull the data from each site into a single page, and having it formatted correctly would be a nightmare.

Comment: Are you planning to implement this client-side in JavaScript?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, client-side as I do not have any control over the domains listed. I have edited my question to show a partially working solution, but so far I can only execute a single link this way.

Comment: @deEr. I was hoping to use ```window.open``` (just because I am a little more familiar with) but what might it look like with ```action="GET" ```?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and inconsistent. There is no such thing as a closing `</input>` tag

Comment: @Rob Didn't catch that... interesting. Edited.

Comment: Put three of those form in the page and you should be good, no?

Comment: I don't think there will be a way to do it without requiring the user to click three times.  Browsers require each new window have its own click event.  You can't open three windows with on click.